# Integer key to date in a named calculation

Tags: ssas, integer-overflow

Trying to do a named calculation in SSAS from a integer key to Quarter.
IntegerDateKey Below:

```
  SalesDateKey
   20100101
   20100101
   20100101
   20100102
   20100102
   20100102
   20100102
```

This doesn't work and no matter how I cast it, I can't get it to work.

```
  CONVERT(char(4), YEAR(SalesDateKey))+
  CASE
      WHEN MONTH(SalesDateKey) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 'Q1'
      WHEN MONTH(SalesDateKey) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN 'Q2'
      WHEN MONTH(SalesDateKey) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN 'Q3'
      ELSE 'Q4'
  END
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please test your findings on a named calculation in SSAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

```
CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, CAST(CAST(SalesDateKey AS char(8)) AS DateTime)) AS 
VARCHAR(4)) + ' - ' +
CASE
   WHEN Month(CAST(CAST(SalesDateKey AS CHAR(8)) AS DATE)) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 
   THEN 'Q1'
   WHEN Month(CAST(CAST(SalesDateKey AS CHAR(8)) AS DATE)) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 
   THEN 'Q2'
   WHEN Month(CAST(CAST(SalesDateKey AS CHAR(8)) AS DATE)) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 
   THEN 'Q3'
   ELSE 'Q4'
END
```